# NServiceBus with WCF on Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, nservicebus, azure-worker-roles

I have the following classes:

```
namespace GAT.Cloud.Integration.WebServices {
    public class DepartureUpdatedService : WcfService<DepartureUpdated, ErrorResponse> {
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace GAT.ESB.Messages.Integration {
    [Serializable]
    public class DepartureUpdated : ICommand {
        public Departure Departure { get; set; }
        public DepartureSeries DepartureSeries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace GAT.Cloud.Integration.Responses {
    public enum ErrorResponse {
        None,
        Fail
    }
}
```

And the following snippet in the app.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="GAT.Cloud.Integration.WebServices.DepartureUpdatedService" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
            <endpoint address="http://<something>.cloudapp.net/WebHttpService/" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="NServiceBus.IWcfService`2[[GAT.ESB.Messages.Integration.DepartureUpdated, GAT.ESB.Messages.Integration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[GAT.Cloud.Integration.Responses.ErrorResponse, GAT.Cloud.Integration.Responses, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />                  
      </service>
  </services>
```

I am getting two errors:

```
The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value 'NServiceBus.IWcfService`2[[GAT.ESB.Messages.Integration.DepartureUpdated, GAT.ESB.Messages.Integration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[GAT.Cloud.Integration.Responses.ErrorResponse, GAT.Cloud.Integration.Responses, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceContractType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.
```

And

```
The 'name' attribute is invalid - The value 'GAT.Cloud.Integration.WebServices.DepartureUpdatedService' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceNameType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.
```

I have no idea what is wrong with this. Does anybody have any ideas? Also, is this the correct set up for it to show up at `http://<something>.cloudapp.net/WebHttpService/` when it is published to Azure as a cloud service?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the endpoint. It should have been:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="NServiceBus.IWcfService`2[[GAT.ESB.Messages.Integration.DepartureUpdated, GAT.ESB.Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[GAT.Cloud.Integration.Responses.ErrorResponse, GAT.Cloud.PhoenixIntegration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]" />
```

Comment: I'm crying, but I don't know why.

Comment: There's just something about NServiceBus.IWcfService`2[[GAT.ESB.Messages.Integration.DepartureUpdated, GAT.ESB.Messages.Integration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[GAT.Cloud.Integration.Responses.ErrorResponse, GAT.Cloud.Integration.Responses, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] that makes it kind of ... um, anti-clean